# VBA Macro Search Difference in Range

Tags: vba, excel

I need to check the range from `A1` to `AY1`, `B1` to `BY1`.... from sheet 1 and compare them with the range from `A1` to `AY1`, `B1` to `BY1`.... from sheet 2 and highlight in yellow the difference in sheet 1.

```
Sub copyWorkingFileToConsolidated()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 5

    Do While Sheet2.Range("A" & i).Value <> ""
        Sheet3.Range("A" & i & ":D" & i).Value = Sheet2.Range("A" & i & ":D" & i).Value
        Sheet3.Range("F" & i & ":Y" & i).Value = Sheet2.Range("E" & i & ":X" & i).Value
        Sheet3.Range("A" & i & ":Y" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    getResourceLevel
End Sub
```

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be doing anything near what you describe. It is, instead, copying data from one sheet to another and painting cells on the destination sheet... not sure what you want here... anyway, did you try to achieve the coloring you mention with conditional formatting instead of VBA?

Comment: Hi, Pasted the wrong code..

Sub checkNewItems()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    
    Do While Sheet1.Range("B" & i + 2).Value <> ""
        If (Sheet2.Range("B" & i + 2).Value <> Sheet3.Range("B" & i + 2).Value) Then Sheet2.Range("B" & i + 2).Interior.Color = 13561798
        If (Sheet2.Range("C" & i + 2).Value <> Sheet3.Range("C" & i + 2).Value) Then Sheet2.Range("C" & i + 2).Interior.Color = 13561798
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub

The problem with this is this is a static code. when someone add a new row from sheet 1 then the the other sheet will consider everything from that as new